# Select Dyntopo field and check it as True

Tags: python, sculpt-mode

I would like to select the Dyntopo and place a check into the field, yet I can only find a toggle script `bpy.ops.sculpt.dynamic_topology_toggle()`.
I'm not sure where I am going wrong. All other sculpt options seem to work.

Comment: You want it to *only* check it, and not uncheck it when the script is run again?

Comment: It needs to be checked when the script runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects have the [`use_dynamic_topology_sculpting`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.use_dynamic_topology_sculpting) property, which allows you to check whether or not dynamic topology is activated. Therefore your script could look like this:

```
import bpy


active_object = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active

if active_object.mode == "SCULPT" and not active_object.use_dynamic_topology_sculpting:
    bpy.ops.sculpt.dynamic_topology_toggle()
```

Comment: BTW: The "use_...._sculpting" link above goes nowhere?! Anyway were would said code go? in a timer firing every second or is there a handler or event listener for when sculpting mode is switched to? and a View3D window becomes active?

Comment: @MasterJames Fixed the link. Like I wrote as a comment to your own question, you likely want to use the `msgbus`. Unfortunately I currently don't have the time to write an answer. The code above simply enables dynamic topology if it isn't already enabled, which was the topic of this question.

Comment: Yes thanks very useful it does show the value for this toggle to add the listener for the properties change. Your input is valued and much appreciated.