# Hooks, Events, Handlers, Listeners in 2.8?

Tags: python, scripting

I wanted to ask how about the current Blender 2.82.7 in 2020 and the status for the long running questions in have experienced and seen often in my brief explorations of Blender coding in the past about the state of affairs regarding Hooks, Events, Handlers, Listeners, or something similar in the API to allow proper unlimited access to everything going on in an efficient way (meaning not just timers polling endlessly etc.).

Let's say you want to know when the "Sculpting Mode" is switched 'on' in any window, so you can call a function to make sure you have Dyntopo enabled. [There would also be less direct things to inject a hook into like the switching to the Sculpting window tab, which you would also have to do since that window would already be in Sculpting Mode, but switching to another window like Modeling forces back to Edit mode and breaks the Dyntopo Mode.]

Of course you don't want to be prompted about it and so this function (below) you can track down in the Info Viewer using the UI, alas it is maybe not the actual command that would be best.

```
bpy.ops.sculpt.dynamic_topology_toggle()
```

Sometimes I see a message there
Dynamic Topology found: face data, disabled
which I suppose is another story.
Anyway if you call the command in a Console you do not get prompted (asked via a popup) to confirm so that's good.

Anyway in this scenario you want to call that function when Sculpting Mode is switched to (or a 3DViewer in that mode is made active).

I have gotten a bit lost looking again in 2020 at the newer 2.8(?) API
Although maybe if you monitored a property change of a 3DViewer AreaSpace becoming active that might be the time to call it (if it is in Sculpting mode?) so that is where you would want to put your 'Hook' or in this case have a custom python script function (aka Handler) is to be called to itself call the dynamic_topology_toggle function 'on' but of course you really want to know what the actual property is and set it to True (or toggle based on it's value/state.

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.AreaSpaces.html#bpy.types.AreaSpaces.active

I suppose the question can be answered in anyway you deem related but ideally the example helps understand what I fear is still missing proper attention in the Current Blender API.

Right so again the questions this example boils down to are can you monitor a system property like Dyntopo and/or put a hook/handler into the API like active window did change or something similar yet?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the currently undocumented [`msgbus`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=msgbus). I don't really understand your criticism regarding "types". What exactly doesn't work as expected and can you elaborate what the "fundamental logic in coding issue" is supposed to be? Checking equality doesn't require getters/setters and since Blender is implemented in C and C++ it uses the concepts that these languages offer. Also keep in mind that you're just working with the Python API that abstracts a lot of things that are happening behind the scenes.

Comment: If you want to know how exactly an operator works (e.g. what other functions it calls) you will have to look at the source code. The *Info* area is not meant to display the entire call stack. There are some API functions that allow to set the state directly instead of toggling.The functions that only allow toggling can be sometimes be annoying, but there are usually ways to infer the current state. For `dynamic_topology_toggle` take a look at [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165588/select-dynotopo-field-and-check-it-as-true/165614#165614).

Comment: Please note that StackExchange is a Q&A website, not a forum. Other websites, such as blenderartists.org, should be used for an open-ended discussion. For the future please limit yourself to one question at a time.

Comment: bpy.msgbus is not documented but only three functions and the doc can be easily obtained from the Python console (@RobertGützkow).

Comment: @lemon I know. The source code can be found [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/python/intern/bpy_msgbus.c). However, unless you know you're looking for `msgbus`, it's not that easy to find.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Robert's comments I found useful and followed up at the link with a similar question. Still I wonder is there a proper place for those kinds of Event Handlers yet? 'Window' has become active event and a View3D's property changed to 'Sculpt Mode' to avoid timers firing endlessly. 'msgbus' needs docs to followup on and finding what the actual properties are that are effected by the toogle functions. Unfortunately bpy.ops.sculpt.sculptmode_toggle() is also not a property like bpy.ops.sculpt.dynamic_topology_toggle() so doing property change listeners is extra challenging.

Comment: Hunting around the source I found this https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/crazyspace.c$388 so the Object has a mode OB_MODE_SCULPT meaning you can't watch for this for the window anyway I guess?

Comment: Next I started looking for some kind of active Window event here https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/lib_query.c$1211 but it seemed way off target (and revoked my thoughts and concerns about type issues) and noticed comments like "this is bad and needs to be changed" etc. continuing this discussion https://devtalk.blender.org/t/is-there-any-way-to-detect-an-active-modal-operation/7184/4 also shows deep issues and furthers my concerns while extending some understanding of the modal loop.

Comment: Anyway it leads to this link https://blenderartists.org/t/detect-if-modal-operator-is-running/1204971/2 and talk about 2.83 (currently I am looking at 2.82.7) and I was noticing "workspace_hook" in there too?!